# can flask `request.remote_addr` can be anything other than IP?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I want to validate against injection via `X-Forwarded-For`

All the resources I'm finding talk about IP address - so I can just verify it is an IP address.

The question is - can it be a hostname?

Comment: yes. both headers will have only the IP addresses

Comment: It can be whatever the forwarding and local servers put in there. Hopefully that is under your control or you shouldn't rely on it in any case. At the very least `X-Forwarded-For:` could legitimately contain a list of IP addresses.

Comment: @hjThanks. Do you have any source to quote (so it'll be official) and put is as an answer?

Comment: @hop - I'm not worried about multiple IP addresses - I'm worried about having a DNS name instead